# How can add kivymd and others modules used in buildozer?

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am using KivyMD create myapp when convert it to apk using buildozer , it seem that buildozer understand just kivy.

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Ros 3

# (str) Package name
package.name = myapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg
....
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add kivymd to your requirements in your buildozer.spec file

Comment: @YacineRe What is the error message you are getting. Post the error log

Comment: after buildozer finish , on testing the app on phone , the app closing .

Comment: But apk compiles fine? Is this your debug apk? Have you changed anything else, like your android architecture or anything?

Comment: i have changed any thing but when buildozer build the app , i don't any word kivymd on screen ,

Comment: Has the app installed correctly on your phone? I am just trying to understand the situation. You build apk. That installs on your phone. You then try and open it and it crashes? Is there any error in your code? Can you run the code fine in your IDE?

Comment: Yeah, i run my app normaly in pycharm , even when start the buildozer without adding kivymd to requirement the app build fine.

Comment: when the buildozer ranning , it download package of python 3 , kivy , but kvymd no  i ro know why

Comment: Are you using a virtual box for Buildozer? If so, have you installed kivymd on it?

Comment: no i am using digitalocean.com Droplet , i didn't insall kivymd

Comment: That's probably why then. If you haven't installed kivymd it can't compile it

Comment: the problem fixed , it was in (source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,xml,iml) my app use xml and iml , so after add these , the app work fine , Thanks c_n_blue

Comment: @YacineRe no problem, glad you got it sorted!